# TortoiseSVN access rights

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have some basic questions regarding access rights on TortoiseSVN. Basic for the pros at least, while a very confusing topic for a newb like me. I've searched high and low but can't seem to find the answers I need.

1. Can users who have read-only access to a file on the repository check-out, edit the file, and check it back in? I read on tortoisesvn forum that this is possible.
2. If the answer is yes for the first question, then what is the point of read-only vs read-write access?
3. the administrator account is able to create users/ groups and provide access rights...can the user with administrative rights also assign admin rights to other users?
4. Who is able to migrate changes from development to production? and how are those access rights provided?

Answer (score 0):

[Read SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/).

TortoiseSVN is a Subversion client. All authorization-related stuff is done on the server-side by the administrator.

**1, 2**. If the user's account has read-only access to the repository or the project inside the repository then he can't commit changes back. He has read-only access. What's point in providing the user with read-only access when he actually has read / write one?

**3**. Server-side stuff. If you have administrative access to the server machine and the Subversion server, then you can customize access rules. Otherwise, you can't